# Deactivate hover state on table rows in Bootstrap Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, bootstrap-table

Is there a way to deactivate the hover state on table rows in [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/)?

It automatically set's it there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default CSS class of the table is `'table table-hover'`. Simply remove the `table-hover` class to remove the effect.

You can remove the hover effect globally for all tables: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1437/

```
$.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults, {classes:'table'});
```

For a single table, you can set `data-classes="table"`: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1436/

```
<table id="table" data-classes="table">
```

Comment: If you create a standart table with Bootstrap Table the default class is `table table-hover`...
How can I just remove it?

Comment: `<table id="table" data-classes="table">` worked fine! thank you!

Comment: @eco - I also found the way to do it globally for all tables, I've edited the answer. Thanks!